# How to interpret the Check Cache and found columns on Glimpse "Views" tab?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, outputcache, glimpse

In the process of investigating slow view rendering, I was looking at the "views" tab and was trying to figure out which user controls were cached and which ones were not.

Usually the first entry shows something like:

```
| Path                     | Check Cache | Found  | Details            |
|--------------------------|-------------|--------|--------------------|
|~/Path/To/UserControl.ascx| true        |  false | Not found in cache |
|~/Path/To/UserControl.ascx| false       |  true  | key    | value     |
```

All user controls appear the same way, regardless of any caching directive such as :

```
OutputCache Duration="3600" VaryByParam="none" Shared="True"
```

Is glimpse broken or have I bungled the output cache directive?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "Check Cache" column in Glimpse has to do with the view engine's cache - not output cache.

For example, given this (less detailed) output:

```
Ordinal | Requested View | View Engine | Check Cache | Found
--------|----------------|-------------|-------------|------
1       | Index          | WebForms    | true        | false
2       | Index          | Razor       | true        | false
3       | Index          | WebForms    | false       | false
4       | Index          | Razor       | false       | **true**
```

What MVC is doing and Glimpse is trying to show is:

1. Ask the first view engine registered (WebForms) to check in its internal cache for a view called `Index` - but it was unable to find that view (which is why "Found" is `false`).
2. MVC does not give up. It then asks the next view engine registered (Razor) to check in its internal cache for a view called `Index` - but it was also unable to find that view.
3. MVC continues to be persistent and goes back to the first view engine (WebForms), asking for the view called `Index` directly, not from cache. In the case of WebForms, this means looking for a `*.aspx` file on disk - but the view was not found.
4. Finally MVC asks Razor again to find the view (this time checking *.cshtml files on disk) and the view is found.

There is a bit more [information about the view tab](http://getglimpse.com/Help/Views-Tab) on the Glimpse site.

I hope this helps!

NOTE: When ASP.NET is in debug mode, WebForms and Razor never cache their views.

Comment: Yes, I stumbled on the feature about caching with debug mode in the interim. Thanks for the help. I have found glimpse to be helpful to me in tracking down problems with application performance.

Comment: the last note about debug mode was vital for me! :)

Comment: Glad to be able to help!

Comment: Really well explained!